# What is this algebraic object (special case of a semigroup)?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids, quivers

Let $(M,*)$ be a finite semigroup. Further we demand the following:

1. Zero element: $\exists0\in M \forall m\in M:0*m=0=m*0$.
2. Left cancelation: $\forall m,n,n'\in M:0\neq m*n =m*n' \Rightarrow n=n'$.
3. Right cancelation: $\forall m,m',n\in M:0\neq m*n =m'*n \Rightarrow m=m'$.
4. Left neutral: $\forall m\in M \exists e\in M:e*m=m$.
5. Right neutral: $\forall m\in M \exists e\in M:m*e=m$.

Special cases of $M$ would be the the following: Let $Q$ be a finite quiver with no cycles, then the set of all paths with its usual multiplication is a finite semigroup and furfills 1-5. Let $G$ be a finite group, then also $G \dot\cup \{0\}$ is a finite semigroup and furfills 1-5. Are objects like this already studied? Does someone know literature about them?

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group (or empty), $G\cup\{0\}$ fulfills this. Are there other examples?

Comment: Thanks for spotting this mistakes, I will edit it!

Comment: It's not hard to get a quiver out of $M$; let the vertices be the set of nonzero idempotents of $M$, and let the edges be the elements of $M$, with head and tail corresponding to left and right neutrals (which are necessarily idempotent). This won't quite recover the original quiver (especially since idempotents will produce loops that weren't there to begin with, as well as the paths), but it at least should indicate that quivers are a good way to think about all of them.

Comment: I agree on that. However in the example of $M = G\dot\cup \{0\}$ for a finite group $G$ the quiver is just one point with several loops. Maybe one would need to add more structure on the edges to also recover such examples.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the "problem" with the quiver having one point and several loops; it seems similar to the category theory idea of a group being a small category with one object (and several invertible morphisms).

Comment: Exel and I study such things extensively in https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.06281 We call them 0-cancellative semigroups but we don't require the neutral conditions. When they occur we say it is 0-cancellative with local units

Comment: For these to come from a category (or quiver of you like) you want the property called categorical at zero

Comment: Kobayashi gave a finitely presented monoid of intermediate growth with these properties

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look into it! This objects came up for me by considering $k$-Algebras for a field $k$ and chosing $k = \mathbb{F}_1$.

Comment: These typically come up from taking a cancelative monoid like a free monoid and factoring out an ideal or doing the same with a cancelative category like the free category on a quiver.

Comment: In our paper we were mostly interested in the infinite case